# Error messages while trying to Boot up my Pc on Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: dual-boot, live-usb, windows-10, hp, 20.10

I have done all the necessary writing of the ISO file using Etcher to my USB stick.
But, during the boot up from BIOS startup, it displays 2 errors messages, image file attached below.

[image]

Comment: Did you verify your ISO?  (https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0) You weren't specific about your boot (how or what was booted provides details as to device with flaws), but your detail looks like bad ISO or bad write to your install media given what you've provided in my opinion.

Comment: Your ISO is likely incomplete or Etcher failed to write it properly.

Comment: My device is HP NOTEBOOK, Ram is 8gb 1 Tb rom, processor is core i3. I used Rufus, the error message being displayed now is "symbol 'grub_file_filters' not found. Entering rescue mode.....grub rescue>